# AspnetBoilerplate modular: The entity type XXX is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Sorry for my bad English, Could anyone help me with this error as below:

I have followed this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/princeppy/ae0f24417f6ccdc7ccc73587ed9f1769) to create a new module application (named Payment) on AspnetZero framework (named FastOne).

In the second DbContext, I change the default conn to my second database and add new entity name BankCode. After add-migration and update-database, everything works well. New database was created with 1 table name BankCode

I went to create a AppService in .Application module project as below:

```
public class BankCodeAppService : FastOneAppServiceBase, IBankCodeAppService
    {
        //from PaymentDbContext
        private readonly IRepository<BankCode> _repository;

        public BankCodeAppService(IRepository<BankCode> repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

       public ListResultDto<BankCodeDto> GetAllBankCodeDto()
        {
            try
            {
                var result = _repository.GetAll().ToList();
                return new ListResultDto<BankCodeDto>(result.MapTo<List<BankCodeDto>>());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my PaymentDbContext

```
[DefaultDbContext]
    [AutoRepositoryTypes(
        typeof(IPaymentRepositoryBase<>),
        typeof(IPaymentRepositoryBase<,>),
        typeof(PaymentRepositoryBase<>),
        typeof(PaymentRepositoryBase<,>)
    )]
    public class PaymentDbContext : FastOneDbContext
    {
        /* Define an IDbSet for each entity of the application */

        public virtual IDbSet<BankCode.BankCode> BankCodes { get; set; }

        //TODO: Define an IDbSet for your Entities...
        public PaymentDbContext() : base("SecondConn") { }
        public PaymentDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString) { }
        public PaymentDbContext(DbConnection connection) : base(connection) { }
    }
```

The api was created successfully, but when I called to it, it returned the error as below:

> The entity type BankCode is not part of the model for the current
>   context.

I tried to debug and realize that the repository is FastOneDbContext instead of PaymentDbContext : [Wrong repository when debugging][2]
I'm totally new with AspNetBoilerplate and module Zero. So could anyone please to help me. Thank

Update: This is my `PaymentRepositoryBase`

```
namespace FastOne.EntityFramework.Repositories
{
    public class PaymentRepositoryBase<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> : FastOneRepositoryBase<TEntity, TPrimaryKey>
        where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
    {
        public PaymentRepositoryBase(IDbContextProvider<PaymentDbContext> dbContextProvider) : base(dbContextProvider) { }
        //do not add any method here, add to the class above (since this inherits it)
    }
    public abstract class PaymentRepositoryBase<TEntity> : PaymentRepositoryBase<TEntity, int>
        where TEntity : class, IEntity<int>
    {
        public PaymentRepositoryBase(IDbContextProvider<PaymentDbContext> dbContextProvider) : base(dbContextProvider) { }
        //do not add any method here, add to the class above (since this inherits it)
    }
}
```

**Update 3**
Thank for your help Aaron, everything goes correctly, this is the newest error, I have searched some solutions but they didn't work. Please help

> No component for supporting the service
>   FastOne.EntityFramework.PaymentDbContext was found

**Update 4**
I tried to add this method to PaymentDataModule:

```
public override void Initialize()
        {
            IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }
```

It worked!, I can see _repository get correct context. but when i run, it raised this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name
>   'dbo.BankCode'.

I realized that the connection was wrong. It was the connstring of the first context

**Update 5**: I found that I have 3 constructors in `PaymentDbContext`. So i removed these lines:

```
public PaymentDbContext() : base("LocalPaymentConn") { }
        //public PaymentDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString) { }
        //public PaymentDbContext(DbConnection connection) : base(connection) { }
```

-->It received the correct connection string. So awesome!! Thanks Aaron and Tien for all your help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inject `IPaymentRepositoryBase` as you have specified in `AutoRepositoryTypes`.

```
public class BankCodeAppService : FastOneAppServiceBase, IBankCodeAppService
{
    private readonly IPaymentRepositoryBase<BankCode> _repository;

    public BankCodeAppService(IPaymentRepositoryBase<BankCode> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

---

**Update 1**

> ComponentActivator: could not instantiate FastOne.EntityFramework.Repositories.PaymentRepositoryBase`1‌​[[FastOne.BankCode.B‌​ankCode, FastOne.Payment.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

Remove `abstract` keyword from the class declaration for  `PaymentRepositoryBase<TEntity>`.

---

**Update 2**

> Target does not implement interface FastOne.Domain.Repositories.IPaymentRepositoryBase`1[[FastOn‌​e.BankCode.BankCode, FastOne.Payment.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]\r\nParameter name: target

Make `PaymentRepositoryBase` implement `IPaymentRepositoryBase`.

```
public class PaymentRepositoryBase<TEntity> : PaymentRepositoryBase<TEntity, int>, IPaymentRepositoryBase<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity<int>
{
    public PaymentRepositoryBase(IDbContextProvider<PaymentDbContext> dbContextProvider) : base(dbContextProvider) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using mutilple dbcontext in the app. So the second context must be inherit from `AbpDbContext` to ABP inject this correctly. See `MultipleDbContextDemo` example on https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-samples.

Hope this will help you.